# How to use Provider for a Switch widget

Tags: flutter, dart

From the examples and those am seeing online, it looks like by by using Provider, we can avoid using Stateful Widgets for Switch() toggling. I could achieve this by using a Stateful widget by having a global variable which I could set via setState().

An example: https://www.tutorialkart.com/flutter/flutter-switch/

But can I achieve this as a stateless widget using Provider for a Switch Widget?

This is my Switch widget:

```
Switch(
  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.greenAccent,
  onChanged: (bool isNoti) {
    Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).toggleNotification(isNotifiable: !isNoti);
    print('Noti: $isNoti'); // always prints false
    print('Noti: ${Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).isNotifiable}'); // always prints true
  },
  value: Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).isNotifiable, // value doesn't change thus no toggle
),
```

Data class used by Provider.

```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool isNotifiable = false;

  void toggleNotification({bool isNotifiable = true}) {
    this.isNotifiable = isNotifiable;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Just to show it in completion, I do wrap it in ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Data>(
      create: (context) => Data(),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.notifications),
        title:  Text('Notifications'),
        trailing: Switch(
          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          onChanged: (bool isNoti) {
            Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).toggleNotification(isNotifiable: !isNoti);
            print('Noti: $isNoti');
            print('Noti Provider: ${Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).isNotifiable}');
          },
          value: Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).isNotifiable,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Always get following output when I click the toggle.

```
Noti: false
Noti Provider: true
```

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Does it seem to be fine? Can you please elaborate the problem?

Comment: @sameerkashyap I am expecting the switch to toggle between ON and OFF. But instead it just stays in ON when I click the Switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found your mistake, You've done everything right expect your switch is not rebuilding and the mistake here is that you've mentioned so that it should not rebuild.

```
trailing: Switch(
          inactiveTrackColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          onChanged: (bool isNoti) {
            Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).toggleNotification(isNotifiable: !isNoti);
            print('Noti: $isNoti');
            print('Noti Provider: ${Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false).isNotifiable}');
          },
          value: Provider.of<Data>(context).isNotifiable,  // remove `listen: false` 
        ),
```

As value is what your switch depends on to rebuild. But the provider is not listening to changed because you've mentioned `listen: false` .

Use

- `Provider.of<Data>(context, listen: false)` when you are reading data such as in callbacks.
- `Provider.of<Data>(context)` use this when your widget needs to rebuild by listening to the changes

Comment: Works, thank you. For anyone referring to this, also note that there is an error with using !isNoti. That would always be false. Should have passed in the inverse of my Data class's isNotifiable value instead.

Comment: Oh yes, `onChanged` already provides the value you don't have to inverse it.

Comment: It is worth remembering that `context.read<YOUR_PROVIDER>()` uses `listen: false` by default, so make sure to use `Provider.of<YOUR_PROVIDER>()` explicitly